# Mocking and testing an Angular resource and function in a directive test using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs

I'm going through the process of refactoring my controller function into more streamlined ones in my directives.

Am reasonably new to Angular and am running into problems mocking and testing my promises within the directives.

Within the function, I call a Box.reboot() from the directive rebootBox.

```
app.directive("rebootBox", ["Box", function(Box) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
      element.bind( "click", function() {
        Box.reboot({id: scope.box.slug}).$promise.then(function(results) {
          scope.box.state = 'rebooting';
        }, function(errors) {
          scope.box.errors = true;
        })
      });
    }
  }
}])
```

My tests pass in the controller specs because I am able to do something like this:

```
fakeFactory = {
  reboot: function () {
    deferred = q.defer();
    return {$promise: deferred.promise};
  }  
  ...
}

MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
  $scope: scope,
  Box: fakeFactory,
});
```

However, I can't get my head around how I am supposed to do this in my directive test?

I've tried this but I don't understand how I can mock what I did in the controller, ie:

```
Box: fakeFactory
```

My directive test looks like this so far:

```
describe('box reboot', function () {

  var $scope,
      element,
      deferred,
      q,
      boxFactory;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $q) {
    $scope = $rootScope;
    q = $q;
    element = angular.element("<div reboot-box></div>");
    $compile(element)($rootScope)

    boxFactory = {
      reboot: function () {
        deferred = q.defer();
        return {$promise: deferred.promise};
      }
    };

  }))

  it("should reboot a box", function() {
    spyOn(boxFactory, 'reboot').andCallThrough()

    $scope.box = {}
    element.click();

    deferred.resolve({slug: 123});
    $scope.$apply()

    expect(boxFactory.reboot).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
  ...
```

Obvs. it fails because I'm spying on boxFactory.

What is the best way to go about testing such a function?

--- EDIT ----

Further to the comment below, I've used $provide to mock the service call:

```
  beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide) {
    boxFactory = {
      get: function () {
        deferred = q.defer();
        return {$promise: deferred.promise};
      },
      reboot: function () {
        deferred = q.defer();
        return {$promise: deferred.promise};
      },
    };
    $provide.value("Box", boxFactory);
```

I can now call deferred.resolve successfully and all my tests pass bar one.

```
expect(boxFactory.reboot).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Is there a specific reason why this fails and how can I get it to pass?

Comment: You can use `$provide` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753009/how-to-inject-a-service-in-a-directive-unit-test-in-angularjs

Comment: Didn't know that existed. Thanks, I'll take a peek tomorrow.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example, I'm still a little confused about how to use.

Comment: Made an edit to show what I've tried, thanks again